# Setting foreground of one specific textblockelement in a listbox - wp7

Tags: windows-phone-7, data-binding, listbox, textblock, foreground

I've got a listbox, which ive bound to an array of strings. The listbox contains a textblock, which has the text of a string in the array. I want to change the foreground of one of those (it may vary which one):

```
 <ListBox x:Name="listBox" ItemsSource="{Binding Options}" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" Width="400" Height="500" Margin="0,200,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" SelectionChanged="ListBox_SelectionChanged" Loaded="listBox_Loaded">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ListBoxItem>
                        <Grid Height="75" Width="400" HorizontalAlignment="Center" >
                            <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding}" Style="{StaticResource SortingOptions}" />
                        </Grid>
                    </ListBoxItem>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```

I just cant seem to get hold of the textblocks, so i can change the foreground on the right one. Does anyone know how i can achieve this? Thanks

Comment: Can you go into detail about what you want to achieve? Changing Text, Color, ...? I am a bit confused by your explanation ;)

Comment: Sorry. What i want is to change the foreground of one specific textblock

Comment: OK, but based on which condition do you want to change it?

Comment: If the string on that textblock is equal to a string i have in one of my singletons (i can do that check easily in the codebehind), i want to change the color.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bind the Foreground property to the same value as Text and use a BindingConverter to create a Brush out of it.
E.g.

```
<Grid.Resources>
  <yournamespace:ColorConverter x:Key="colConverter"/>
<Grid.Resources>


<TextBlock 
  HorizontalAlignment="Center"
  Text="{Binding}"
  Foreground="{Binding, Converter={StaticResource colConverter}}"
  Style="{StaticResource SortingOptions}" />
```

Add your converter class:

```
  public class ColorConverter : IValueConverter
  {
  public object  Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
  {
      // TODO: match from the value parameter to a color.

      return new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
  }

  public object  ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
  {
      throw new NotImplementedException();
  }
}
```

Comment: That is so easy and brilliant. Why didnt i think of that? Thanks alot!

Comment: well, i do get an error on this line:     Foreground="{Binding, Converter={StaticResource SortingColorConverter}}"   says somthing about an unexpected comma. Is it because it only says binding perhaps?

Comment: Right. Did you try and remove the comma?

Comment: oh yeah. i know i look stupid now, but i thought the comma had to be there, since its always there when you bind to something with a name.  But hold on, didnt work after all. Argh! i get a data error: cant convert visibility to brush. lots of text and stuf

Comment: Where are you binding the Visibility? I tried it out and it works nicely.

Comment: My bad. Everything works as a charm now. Thanks ALOT, and have a good day ;)